# How to automatically attach E-mail, not embed them

Tags: macos, mail.app

How can I add E-Mail-Attachments automatically to an E-Mail, without integrating them? 
Especially photos!

Menu -> Edit -> Attachments... doesn't work!

I use OS X Lion (10.7.2) and Mail (5.1).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not integrating them? Do you mean not have them shown in line with the rest of text?

Comment: Yes! I want to Drag&Drop Files in the E-Mail body, and want a little icon on the end of the email!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this individually by dragging the image(s) in, right clicking on them and clicking "View as Icon". You can select multiple images at once to do this as well.

If you would like Mail to do this automatically with all attachments, try the following Terminal command:

> `defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes`

Relaunch Mail for this to take effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know this, but i want mail to automatically to this!

Comment: I've updated my answer with the correct information.

Comment: Mhh...i think this is just the view! On the other Mac, the picture is showing as a picture in the e-mail, not as an attachment!

Comment: Oh my end, it shows the attachment but uses a preview of the attachment as the icon. This is probably a Lion UI thing.

Comment: You don't really have that much control over how the receiver displays the email, but if you zipped the file before sending it then if there is any preview it should just be whatever icon the mail client uses for a zipped file.

Comment: So, files will always be attached to e-mails? thanks for the help!

Comment: @nextrufus Yes. The files will always be attached to the emails, even if Mail shows them inline with text. That's Apple's fancy way of doing things. If you send the email to a Windows user with the photos inline with the text, they'll still see them as attachments.

Answer (score 1):

Mail offers you no way to change the attachment to not be inline. There are ways to change the appearance of it, using 'View as icon', and there is a command line instruction that will set that as the default. But this only applies to you, not the recipient of any messages that you send.

However, it doesn't have to be this way. The [MIME protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202889%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) does allow for non-inline attachments. But the only way I've found that allows you to utilise this is to use [Lokiware's Attachment Tamer](http://lokiware.info/Attachment-Tamer), currently $14.99.