# Change mail back to embedding attachments

Tags: terminal

I wanted to attach a photo and not embed it so I did the following:

> If you would like Mail to do this automatically with all attachments, try the following Terminal command:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing -bool yes
> ```
>
> Relaunch Mail for this to take effect.

<sup>[How to automatically attach E-mail, not embed them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36641/how-to-automatically-attach-e-mail-not-embed-them)</sup>

I only wanted to do this temporarily, but now can't change it back.  Can someone help me to change it back to automatically embedding photo?

Answer (score 1):

```
defaults delete com.apple.mail DisableInlineAttachmentViewing
```